# Angular PWA error: Bootstrap call not found

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular11, angular-pwa

I tried

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

But I got an error saying (additionally, it is not creating/modifying any files in the project)

```
Bootstrap call not found
```

Here are the specifications

```
npm: '7.20.0'
node: '12.18.3',
angular-cli: '11.2.14' (project)
```

And here is the screenshot of the error
[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: Are you using the Bootstrap CSS framework? If yes, then can you verify that you have called it in angular.json correctly?

Comment: No, I am not using Bootstrap framework in my project. I am using Material instead.

Comment: Can you share your angular.json and your project directory structure?

Comment: I just installed this package
`ng add @angular-architects/module-federation`
which modifies among others `main.ts`

Then i added angular materials and got the same error as you.
But the app compiles and seems to work, so I think it is the schematic that is complaining trying to modify the `main.ts` file. even though I cannot see that angular material does that in another project I have material installed on.

Comment: Any news on how to fix this error? I also tried to temporary restore the original main.ts file but without luck.

Comment: Do you use bootstrapApplication (standalone components)? Then this bug might be related to your problem: github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/23316

For a workaround see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75430579/12240480.