# "ng add @angular/pwa" Bootstrap call not found in angular standalone project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to add @angular/pwa but it showing me "Bootstrap call not found". Things to mention that I removed `app.module.ts` and I'm using standalone component in every places like components there is no module existence right now. So, Now my application getting bootstrap from `main.ts` as like bellow,

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(AuthService),
    importProvidersFrom(ErrorHandlerService),
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule),
    importProvidersFrom(
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),
      BrowserAnimationsModule
    ),
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: ErrorHandlerService
    }
  ]
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

```
Angular Version:
Angular CLI: 14.1.1
Node: 16.16.0
Package Manager: npm 8.15.1 
OS: linux x64

Angular: 14.1.1
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1401.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.1.1
@angular-devkit/core            14.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.1.1
@schematics/angular             14.1.1
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript                      4.6.4
```

Comment: Are you running this command in the correct folder?

Comment: yes , I'm running in my project root directory. @KonradLinkowski

Answer (score 7):

I created a temporary app.module installed pwa and then moved changes from app.module to main.ts:

temporarily edit main.ts and add app.module:

src/main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

app/app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule { }



npm install @angular/pwa --save-dev 

nx g @angular/pwa:ng-add --project=champ-ng


CREATE apps/champ-ng/ngsw-config.json
CREATE apps/champ-ng/src/manifest.webmanifest
CREATE apps/champ-ng/src/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png
CREATE apps/champ-ng/src/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png
CREATE apps/champ-ng/src/assets/icons/icon-152x152.png
CREATE apps/champ-ng/src/assets/icons/icon-192x192.png
CREATE apps/champ-ng/src/assets/icons/icon-384x384.png
CREATE apps/champ-ng/src/assets/icons/icon-512x512.png
CREATE apps/champ-ng/src/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png
CREATE apps/champ-ng/src/assets/icons/icon-96x96.png
UPDATE workspace.json
UPDATE apps/champ-ng/src/app/app.module.ts
UPDATE apps/champ-ng/src/index.html
```

copy the changes to app.module.ts to main.ts

```
importProvidersFrom(ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: !isDevMode(),
      // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the application is stable
      // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
    })),
```

delete app.module and restore main.ts

Comment: If you make the project as standalone, you will face this error. by dividing the module as Rob said My pwa work now.

Comment: Worked for me too, I had a bootstrapped project

Comment: Worked for me too with Angular 17 :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with custom code in main.ts.
I reverted it back to the default and successfully added @angular/pwa.

After that you can revert to your custom main.ts.

Comment: What about app.module.ts? Did you remove this or leave it as default?

Comment: @SefatAnam I have kept the app.module.ts

Comment: I removed app.module.ts , i don't want to add app.module.ts because without this app is running well in standalone manner.